# Get branch name being pushed in pre-push hook git

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am trying to check if the branch needs rebase before pushing to remote with the command `git push` only.

I am trying to write a script on pre-push hook which will get the branch name being pushed, check if rebase is needed and if it does, it will prevent push operation.

```
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha 
do 
    echo $local_ref
    echo $local_sha 
    echo $remote_ref
    echo $remote_sha
done
```

I expect to get the variables intended, but I am getting nothing in output.

How I can get the branchname being pushed?

Comment: Is the code in `.git/hooks/pre-push`? Is the file executable? Is something pushed when you run `git push`? Because if there is nothing to push `git` doesn't call hooks. Add `exit 1` at the end of the script to prevent all pushes and continue debugging.

Comment: Yes code is present in `.git/hooks/pre-push`, also it is getting called when I echo something. Only issue is, I am not getting stdin which git says in it documentation of pre-push hook.